# Why do map, foreach and reduce not use the iterator function on Symbol.iterator?

Tags: javascript

Why do `map`, `foreach`, and `reduce`, not use the iterator function on `Symbol.iterator`?

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for(let x = 0; x < this.length; x++) { yield this[x]*2 }
    }
}

const log = console.log
const arr = new MyArray(1,2,3)
console.log([...arr]) // [2,4,6]
log(arr.map((i) => i)) // [1,2,3]
```

And:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3]
Object.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(arr), Symbol.iterator, { 
    value: function*() {
        for(let x = 0; x < this.length; x++) { yield this[x]*2 }
    }
})

const log = console.log
log([...arr]) // [2,4,6]
log(arr.map((i) => i)) // [1,2,3]
```

Comment: I'd guess that `forEach` and the other method predate `Symbol.iterator` so they don't use it for historical reasons. I've got no official source to back that up, though.

Comment: The spec clearly indicates that the functions do simple iteration from 0 up to the value of the `length` property.

Comment: Given all of those methods pre-date the general iterator protocol, they probably just implemented them using existing `Array` features directly, which avoids overhead from general iterator protocol usage. Those methods are all *very* `Array` specific after all (they include information on the index, skip unassigned indices, etc.).

Comment: @Pointy: `map` at least is sparse array friendly; [the callback isn't invoked for unassigned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes that's true, but it still doesn't use the iterator behavior.

Comment: To be fair, it's just an interface.  Even if I implement an interface, I might still go through an obtuse alternative that might return the same thing the implemented interface would if it means I don't have rewrite legacy code.  Do you have a use case where this adversely affects what you're trying to do, or are you asking out of curiosity?

Comment: Curiosity. Aesthetically it feels weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "old" Array methods are explicitly specified such that iteration is in terms of a simple sequence of numeric indexes. See for example [the ES2016 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach).

You can use `Array.from(arr)` to make your iterator work, and then call `.forEach()` on the result.

Note that for some of the iteration methods, the specified behavior is to only invoke the callback for indexes that actually have an assigned value. Because using the iterator would mean iterating through *all* the values, that would be problematic. All the iterator function can do for unassigned values is return `undefined`, but then it'd be ambiguous; does it mean the slot in the container has never been assigned a value, or does it mean it was explicitly assigned `undefined`?

Comment: OK, but why not have the default iterator work this way, and then use a replacement if present?

Comment: @52d6c6af you'd have to ask the language committee. I think I agree that it *could* have been specified that way, though for `.map()` it'd be tricky to know whether an `undefined` value was actually present in the container.

Comment: So the reason might be sparse arrays.

Comment: @52d6c6af right. I guess it'd be possible to add a special pre-defined Symbol that'd mean "there's nothing here" from an iterator, but that might make a mess.